# How to trigger keyboard interrupt

Tags: python, twitter

I'm trying to use Twitter API to stream tweets, but I don't know how to stop the streaming automatically, unless using keyboard interrupt ( control+c).

```
import tweepy
import time
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        #print data
        tweet = data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source')[0]
        print tweet
        saveThis = str(time.time()) + '::' + tweet
        saveFile = open('twitDB.csv','a')
        saveFile.write(saveThis)
        saveFile.write('\n')
        saveFile.close
        return True
    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["car"])
```

so, how can I stop the data streaming automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain a `counter` which you increment and check in `on_status()`.
Once you reach your limit `returning False` should stop the stream. Try it like.

```
def on_status(self, status):
    print status.text
    self.n += 1
    if self.n < 20:
        return True
    else:
        print 'maxnum = '+str(self.n)
        return False
```

Comment: `self.n += 1` is typically preferred to `self.n = self.n + 1`